# Image path that includes a variable in template section

Tags: vue.js, template-literals

I need to use a variable as part of an image path in the template section of my component:

```
<img :src="`@/assets/img/${variable}.svg`" />
```

The `${variable}` part works fine, however the beginning of the path doesn't work in the sense that `Vue` keeps "@/" as it is, which of course doesn't make sense from the browser's perspective.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use require to get an image from assets folder:

```
<img :src="require(`@/assets/img/${variable}.svg`)" />
```